# Center a div in ie7 and ie8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I would like to simply center a div in the middle of the window. Currently using

```css
.notSupported {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  z-index: 1000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="notSupported">Your browser is not supported</div>
```

In `ie7` it results in the div appearing top left corner and in `ie8` center top.

Comment: you have set a width and height to that div to place it

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#middle { 
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

/* for IE7 and below */
#middle {
  *position: absolute;
  *top: 50%;
  *width: 100%;
  *text-align: center;
  }

#center {
  *position: relative;
  *top: -50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="center">Center me !</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Block doesn't work in IE7.

You have to use zoom:1 and block as a hack or without hack from a different css only for ie7.

```
.notSupported {
    display: block;
    *display: block;
    *zoom:1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 500px;
    max-height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    z-index: 1000;
    text-align: center;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
}
```